# call to get another page inside div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a ecommerce site in which a dialog page provides the user with cart information and upon clicking "check out" I am trying to grab my cc processing vendor's page and load it into the div.

I am loading it into the dialog div by calling:

```
 $('#viewCart').html('<object data="https://someCC.com/amount=<?php echo $totalCharges;?>&UMinvoice=<?php echo $_SESSION['cartId'];?>">');
```

my problem is that the dialog contains the page, but only in a small portion of the dialog as seen here.
    [image]

how can i adjust it so that a) the dialog is larger, and b the resulting page fits in the dialog?

edit::::

```
 $('#viewCart').dialog(
    {
            autoOpen:false,
            width: 1400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            buttons: 
    {

            "CheckOut": function() 
            {

 $('#viewCart').html('<object data="https://someCC.com/amount=<?php echo $totalCharges;?>&UMinvoice=<?php echo $_SESSION['cartId'];?>">');
            },
            "Cancel": function() 
            {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
    }
    });
```

and at bottom of page:

```
 <div id='viewCart'></div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Ajax?

Comment: i made a mistake and retitled question, apologies.

Comment: post your html markup such that we can see what #viewCart looks like.  Also post the code that includes the 1 line you showed us above

Comment: done.  there are no styles on #viewcart in any css. just a standard dialog

Comment: I found solution,  need to add width and height to object in my call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add attributes to object.

```
$('#viewCart').html('<object width="1100' height="1100" data="https://someCC.com/amount=<?php echo $totalCharges;?>&UMinvoice=<?php echo $_SESSION['cartId'];?>">');
        },
```